# Android - Read file from storage "Permission Denied" despite inline permissions and manifest permissions

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to get past a java.io.FileNotFoundException:(Permission Denied) error even though I think I've covered all of the bases. I am using an intent uri so the user can find the file themselves.

I already have necessary permissions in manifest and am requesting permissions at runtime.

in my manifest:

open folder opens the intent where a user can pick a file

```
public void openFolder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

and then in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    else if(requestCode==2 && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        classificationFragment.givePath(data.getData(), this);
    }
}
```

I get denied trying to open the file

```
public void givePath(Uri data, Context context) {
    checkReadExternalStoragePermission();
    checkWriteExternalStoragePermission();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getPath(this.getContext(), data))); // ERROR HERE
        //do some stuf with the file
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

these should check permissions at runtime

```
public void checkWriteExternalStoragePermission() {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}

public void checkReadExternalStoragePermission() {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d("REQUEST_CODE",String.valueOf(requestCode));
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Write Storage Permission (already) Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Write Storage Permission (already) Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been stuck for a while. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55370155/edit) your post to include your targetSDK API level and on which OS version/device/emulator you are testing on.

Comment: What is getPath(this.getContext(), data)?  You can just use new File(data) as File takes Uri in constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() allowed me to access the the file

```
File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String[] elements = data.getPath().toString().split("/");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Root + "/FolderName/" + elements[elements.length-1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

requestPermission is not blocking method. That means, it prompts the permission dialog and return immediately before "ok" or "cancel" is clicked by user. So this piece of code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getPath(this.getContext(), data))); // ERROR HERE
    //do some stuf with the file
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

is called before the required permission is granted.

Solution is to move this piece of code to after

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Write Storage Permission (already) Granted", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```